# How to make TextFormField responsive on flutter for web apps?

Tags: flutter

I' am trying to make TextFormFields, that are next to each other in a row, responsive stacking them over each other like columns when the window shrinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Wrap widget, it breaks into the next line if there is no more space

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Wrap widget, it works similarly to the Row widget but this time when there is no more space available, it automatically shifts to the next line.

[Here is a link to the Flutter documentation for the Wrap widget](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwign7aj1Nb6AhX3wAIHHQl0DhMQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.flutter.dev%2Fflutter%2Fwidgets%2FWrap-class.html&usg=AOvVaw2nLp55jywWSt-uNCLu8MmX)